# Regex to enter only alphabets and donot enter any other characters

Tags: regex

I have a Regex which contains the following .Is this suitable restricting the user only to enter alphabets and do not allow numbers ,special characters such as (',@#$%^&*())

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: What language/regex library are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it also does not allow accented characters and other non-ASCII letters (ä, à, ñ, ß and many others).

`^\p{L}+$` is an alternative for this scenario, if your regex engine is Unicode-aware.

Comment: Just for the record, Tim :) it turns out that `\pL` is not strictly synonymous with `\p{Alphabetic}`; there are 1006 such code points in Unicode 6. For example, things like <ⅷ> U+2177 SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL EIGHT and <Ⓐ> U+24B6 CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A are both `\p{Alphabetic}` and `\PL`, weirdly enough. Also be careful in Java, where `\p{Alpha}` really means what others’d call `(?=\p{ASCII})\p{Alpha}`, or sometimes `\p{POSIX_Alpha}`. Running `ˋunichars -a '\PL' '\p{Alphabetic}' | wc -lˋ == 1006`; get it from [here](http://training.perl.com/scripts/) if you want to run your own such tests.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Yes, it only allows a..z and A..Z. This means a space is also not allowed. At least one character, so an empty string is not matched either.

Answer (score 1):

That regex will only match alphanumeric characters from a to z, upper- and lowercase. So I guess that is what you wanted. By the way: because of the plus sign, at least one of the characters from your character class is required.